# AngularJS : Resolving self-chaining promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I know that promises can be chained, as in this example:

```
// we also have deferA, deferB and deferC as the corresponding defer objects
promiseB = promiseA.then(function(result) {
    // do stuff to resolve B
});

promiseC = promiseB.then(function(result) {
    // do stuff to resolve C
});
```

Now if I call `deferA.resolve(data)` this will resolve `promiseA`, its `then` method will run, and then `promiseB` is resolved. Finally promiseB's `then` will run and resolve `promiseC`. Flat and simple (hope I got this right).

However, what happens if a promise chains with itself?

**If I change the above example into this:**

```
// we also have deferA and deferB as the corresponding defer objects
promiseA = promiseA.then(function(result) {
    // do stuff to...?
});

promiseB = promiseA.then(function(result) {
    // do stuff to resolve B
});

deferA.resolve(data);
```

Now what happens? What's the order of execution?

**More over, what about this:**

```
// we also have deferA and deferB as the corresponding defer objects
promiseA = promiseA.then(function(result) {
    // do stuff to...?
});

deferA.resolve(data);

promiseB = promiseA.then(function(result) {
    // do stuff to resolve B
});
```

What would happen in this case?

Comment: `What would happen`  .. can't you log these to console and find out?

Comment: @charlietfl sure I can, but I was asking about the logic and sequences behind it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't about promises, it's about references in JavaScript.

When you do:

```
p = p.then(function(){...
```

You are changing the promise `p` is referring to, you are not changing the promise the deferred object will resolve when you fullfill/reject it - that's still the same `p` from before you re-assigned to it. So in your example code:

```
promiseA = promiseA.then(function(result) { // THIS WILL EXECUTE FIRST
    // do stuff to...?
});

promiseB = promiseA.then(function(result) { // THIS WILL EXECUTE SECOND
    // do stuff to resolve B
});

deferA.resolve(data);
```

---

When you attach more than one `.then` handler to a promise as in:

```
var p = first.then(...

var p2 = first.then(...
```

I'm assuming a Promises/A+ implementation here. The spec guarantees that both `.then` handlers will execute when `first` fulfills. It will always happen in the order they were added.

So, in the above case:

- First promiseA will resolve
- Then the upper promiseA.then will run (the one that was added first)
- Then the bottom promiseA.then will run (the one that was added later)

Resolving the deferred before or after the `.then` addition will not change the result in a noticeable way (trivia: this is not the case with jQuery promises which is a big problem with them).

---

It is possible to create a circular promise chain though, just a bit harder. Just like it's possible to create an infinite loop. Good promise libraries will either run it, or throw a circular reference error.

Comment: So about the reference, what if I write ```deferA.promiseA = deferA.promiseA.then(...)```? This will surely change the defer object.

Comment: @Xavier_Ex that depends on the deferred implementation - this sort of thing (as well as throw safety) is why some libraries do `.promise()` and some don't give you direct access to a deferred using the better promise constructor instead. Since you tagged this [tag:angularjs], as you can see [it won't change the defer object](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/q.js#L211-L225)'s resolve method (just its .promise value) since it's closure bound. Still, you should definitely avoid this, and this might change in an Angular update in the future.

Comment: In your example where you have `p = first.then()` and `p2 = first.then()`, you say that both `.then()` handlers will run when `first` is resolved and they will run in order.  Is that the same as `first.then().then()` or are the two `.then()` handlers run synchronously (where the second one doesn't wait for the first one to resolve - it just waits for the callback to return)?  Is my question clear?

Comment: The two `.then` handlers run synchronously in order if you don't re-assign promiseA, and they run asynchronously if you do `promiseA.then(..); promiseA.then(...)` in the order you attached the handler.